# Calling view from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render

I'm in following situation:
I have view 'homepage.html.erb' in HomepageControler and I have view 'new.html.erb' in controller User- simple_form with fields with name etc. and I'd like to make this new.html.erb view part of homepage.html.erb.

I created partial _new.html.erb with the same content as new.html.erb and in homepage.html.erb I'm calling

```
 render "users/new", user: User.new,
```

but I suppose that it isn't the best solution. Could someone advise me better option?

Comment: What don't you like about it, having to define `user` with the render? You should be able to do `<% form_for User.new do |user| %>` etc...